# UIButton setImage not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I have following code and when I call this method, it doesn't change the image of the button although there are images in the resources.

```
-(void)changeButton:(NSString*)button withURL:(NSString*)url {
    timetableURL = url;

    UIImage *btnImage;

    if ([button isEqual:@"Browser"]) {
        btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browser-button.png"];
        [safariBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onSafariButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else if ([button isEqual:@"Timetable"]) {
        btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browser-timetable.png"];  
        [safariBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onTimetableButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    [safariBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnImage release];
}
```

**UPDATED**

FYI: It's a button upside UIToolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things that seem to be wrong with your code:

[btnImage release] 
You've created that image using autorelease, you are not responsible for its release. This will most likely end up in weird stuff happening, i.e. what you encountered.

Are you sure that btnImage has contents after that if statement? is there a possibility that button is not equal to @"Browser" nor @"Timetable"?

Also, make sure the button is in its normal state.

Cheers

Comment: I removed release and double checked that the button is equal to timetable.

Comment: And still the issue? If so, try placing a breakpoint in the line in which you set the image to the button, make sure both are valid objects. And remember to check for the button state, if it is disabled for example, you wont be seeing any changes

Comment: Hve you checked the button is in the normal state?

Comment: How to check this in XCode? I have also updated my question with more info.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check its state in the debugger, you can use something like this in the command line: 
p [btn state]

Comment: I am doing NSLog(@"%d", [safariBtn state]); and it prints 0

Comment: hey I figured out the problem. The button was not linked to the "File's Owner".

Answer (score 2):

Try This ,

**[safariBtn setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];**

No need to release btnImage ...

Comment: Thanks, this helped me A LOT. I was setting the background image on the interface builder so using "setImage:forState:" resulted on having the 2 images at the same time, nothing visible initially, but when disable the button as the 2 images go to alpha .5 you can see both of them :P

Answer (score 0):

i think this should help you...

```
    [safariBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"browser-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[button isEqual:@"Browser"]
```

To

```
[button isEqualToString:@"Browser"]
```

isEqual is testing for object equality, not string equality.

EDIT: OK, you say your button is inside a toolbar. In this case I assume you have added it as a customview to a UIBarbuttonItem? You need to go through the bar button item and set the image property on the custom view of the bar button item, I think (though I'm not sure) once you've added a button as a custom view, the bar button item makes it's own copy so you are not talking to it any more via safariBtn.

You can access the toolbar items via

```
for (UIBarButtonItem *barItem in self.toolbar.items)
```

Assuming this code is in your viewController. Your safariBtn will then be accessible via `barItem.customView`

Comment: Have you checked with logging / breakpoints that safariBtn and btnImage are definitely not `nil` at the point of setting the image? I'm assuming safariBtn is a class ivar? It seems unusual not to be passing the button in as a parameter, but passing a string instead.

Comment: safariBtn is of type UIButton and I can see btnImage isn't null.

Comment: Actually it's UIButton and I have set image to it already using property but at runtime I want to change the image again.

Comment: How are you adding it to the toolbar, then? Can you show that code?

Comment: Well I just drag and drop UIButton to UIToolbar and it stick to it.

Comment: I think you may be right. How can iterate through UIToolbar items?

Comment: hey I figured out the problem. The button was not linked to the "File's Owner".

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you :  set the titles of button where you created it and then control if it equals the title.

```
[safariBtn setTitle:@"Safari" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

then control

```
-(void)changeButton:(NSString*)button withURL:(NSString*)url {
timetableURL = url;

UIImage *btnImage;

if ([button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:@"Safari"]) {
    btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browser-button.png"];
    [safariBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onSafariButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
else if ([button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:@"Timetable"]) {
    btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browser-timetable.png"];  
    [safariBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onTimetableButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

[safariBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnImage release];
```

}

Comment: `button` is passed in as an `NSString`, not a `UIButton`, so won't have a titleForState method - do you mean `[safariBtn titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:`?